# Delphi 7 colour coding

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

My copy of Delphi 7 has these really helpful colour coding sections to show where `if` statements and loops begin and end, etc...

[image]

What are these called, and how do I turn them on in other copies of Delphi 7 which don't have them displayed? Or, do I need to install something?

Comment: Like Remy said, it must be someting like CnPack. But FWIW, your formatting above is totally whacky anyway. And if - else if ladder is formatted differently, normally, and the for loop should be at the same indentation level as the first if.

Comment: I can post a comic how to setup this thing with CnWizards. Personally I would prefer doing drugs than working with such code editor :)

Comment: The ladder seems to stop in your code after `Else Suit := 'C';`because there is a semicolon there. So the `For Count2 := 1 to 13`should start way back more left at the same level as the first if. This is not very readable

Comment: @GuidoG I don't like using `else if` on separate lines like this, I find it very tacky and ugly. I always use `else if` on a single line. It helps keep all the `else`s at the same indent level.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree `else if` should stay together on the same line, not the `if`beneath the `else`. The code from the OP is very hard to read and misleading

Comment: Thanks for the tips, two answers for the price of one! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is definitely NOT something that is built-in to Delphi 7's code editor. There are 3rd party plugins for doing things like that. Castalia, cnPack, etc, just to name a couple. Check your IDE to see what particular packages are installed.

Comment: CodeRush for Delphi was another that was very popular back then but stopped support at Delphi 7 with a final release by DevExpress dated 16 May 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have to install 3rd party in D7 to get this working. It's actually called 'structural highlighting'

With more recent versions (XE2+, not sure) of RAD studio you can make use of the IDE's option to connect the `begin..end` blocks with lines. Check the attached screenshots. It also works for other blocks like `case..end`, `try..finally..end`, `try.except..end` and `repeat..until`.

[image: Structural highlighting in action]

[image: Structural highlighting option]

**BTW** This answer was copied by special request from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855823/statement-expected-but-function-found-error-in-my-function-code/50858076#50858076)