# Statement expected but Function found error in my function code

Tags: delphi, pascal

So below is the module of code I have created to verify a user input is between a range but this error keeps appearing below it ' statement expected but function found', any ideas anyone? Many thanks

```
function get_choice(var Options: integer): integer;
      var
      choice: integer;

      begin
        while (true) do
          begin
              write('choose option 1 to', Options);

              try
                readln(choice);
                if (choice>=1) and (choice <=Options) then
                    get_choice := choice
                else
                    write('invalid range');
              except
                 write('not a number');
          end;
      end;
```

Comment: are you going to tell use which line causes the error?

Comment: Does `write('choose option 1 to', Options);` compile? Don't you have to `write('choose option 1 to', IntToStr(Options));`

Comment: The error occurs on code after that presented in the question .......

Comment: @Mawg, The [System.Write](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Write) can handle many types of arguments: *`Each output expression must be of a type Char, one of the Integer types (Byte, Shortint, Word, Longint, Cardinal), one of the floating-point types (Single, Real, Double, Extended, Currency), one of the string types (PChar, AnsiString, ShortString), a packed string, or one of the Boolean types (Boolean, Bool).`*

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on that. Maybe I am remembering old days(?). That's good to know (+1)

Comment: @Mawg: `Write` and `Writeln` are from the very old days. They don't need things like `IntToStr` or similar conversion routines. Both are "compiler magic" routines, i.e. the compiler knows them and generates different code sequences depending on the arguments. This also makes them accept multiple different arguments, which was otherwise not possible before `array of const` was introduced. FWIW, nowadays, such functions are called "intrinsics" by some.

Comment: Lolx! I have probably been needlessly calling calling `IntToStr()` with Write and()` for a few decades now :-)

Comment: @Mawg: you may want to read up on those routines: Write, Writeln, Read, Readln and see that some of them even have extra formatting options, like `Write(I:8, J:8);`which formats I and J right in their own "fields" of each 8 characters. Very useful for console programs that should quickly (and *readably*) output the results of a simple test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed an `end`:

```
              try
                readln(choice);
                if (choice>=1) and (choice <=Options) then
                    get_choice := choice
                else
                    write('invalid range');
              except
                 write('not a number');
              end;
         end
      end;
```

Try `try..except` block must have its own end.

Comment: Oh gosh, yes! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

As Sharam already stated, you missed the `end` of the `try..except..end` block. Nevertheless, I think I can enhance the answer a bit with some tips, to help avoiding this in you future.

- keep your (`begin .. end` blocks on the same column. Same for `try..except..end`, `try..finally..end` and `repeat..until` blocks off course.
- make use of the IDE's option to connect the begin and and blocks with lines. "structural highlighting. Check the attached screenshots.

[image: Structural highlighting in action]

[image: Structural highlighting option]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked

Comment: I think otherwise. Helping out with a tip to avoid the same mistake in the future should be rewarded, not downplayed. Thanks for the comment anyway. I would rather like to put this in a comment in stead of an answer, but unfortunately my reputation does not allow that yet. (26/50)

Comment: Then you should earn the reputation first. I'm sorry, but that's site policy as has been discussed on meta many times. This answer would be fine if you answered the question as well. It doesn't matter if it's already been answered. The baseline, bare minimum, is to answer the question asked. That's not negotiable. If you want to add more then that's great. So you could address my criticism simply by an edit that addressed the question.

Comment: Thanks David, I got it now, and updated the answer. I'll see if I find some time to check the meta discussions.

Comment: Many thanks - I can see what David means but this is really useful for me and coincidentally was the exact question I asked previously and this is a much better answer so if you copy it over to there I will make this the favoured answer! Annoyingly my copy doesn't have Structural highlighting under the color tab for some reason. Cheers anyway

Comment: @H.Hasenack - this is the question title 'Delphi 7 colour coding' - I'll delete this comment when you have seen it to keep this post succinct

Comment: Upvoted because this answer is useful to avoid the *same problem* in the future